# SQL запрос на количество первых сообщений в период времени

Tags: sql

Подскажите пожалуйста SQL запрос чтобы получить количество первых сообщений (action = sendMess) в определенный период времени из Таблицы UserAction?
Например, количество пользователей отправивших первое сообщение в январе 2019 года

| userId | dateAction | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 2018-12-05 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 111111 | 2019-01-12 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 333333 | 2019-01-11 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 333333 | 2019-02-03 15:16:16 | delMess |
| 555555 | 2020-01-29 15:16:16 | delMess |
| 666666 | 2022-01-12 15:16:16 | updMess |
| 333333 | 2022-01-12 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 777777 | 2019-01-15 15:16:16 | sendMess |

Ожидаемый рез: 2
(пользователи 333333 и 777777)

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Comment: Версия субд sql 8.0